# How to export beautifulsoup parsed data to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse data, and now I want to save it to a csv file. I am able to create a csv file; however, when I open the file it is blank. What should I write for writing to a csv file?

Script:

```
university = {}

for x in soup.find_all('p'):
    name_tag = x.find('strong')
    if name_tag != None:
    name = name_tag.text
    t = x.text
    m = re.findall('\$([0-9]*)', t)
    if m != []:
        print(name +', ' + m[0])
```

Part of output:

```
Harvard University:, 400
Stanford University:, 400
Stanford University:, 400
```

Writing to a csv file:

```
import csv

with open ('gifts.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    writer=csv.writer(file)
    for row in university:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: From your code, It seems like you are not adding anything in your university dict. Add your parsed data in university dict in then over over it and also there you need to call file close function at the end of csv write code.

Comment: I thought row in university would add my parsed data. If not, how do I add to my university dict?

Comment: When I print, I do get the output that I need though.

Comment: can u show output of university variable?

Comment: @AkashWankhede, just showed part of my output

Comment: you didn't add anything to your variable `university`.

Comment: @Tiny.D: How can I add to my variable university?

Comment: @dancemc15 check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add anything to your variable `university` , change your code to :

```
import csv
university = []

for x in soup.find_all('p'):
    name_tag = x.find('strong')
    if name_tag != None:
        name = name_tag.text
        t = x.text
        m = re.findall('\$([0-9]*)', t)
        if m != []:
            university.append([name +', ' + str(m[0]]) # append to variable university

with open('gifts.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in university:
        writer.writerow(row)
```